# Airflow DAG run fails when task is up for retry

Tags: airflow

In my default args for a DAG I have set the `retry` and `retry_delay` parameters. When I monitor the UI, upon a task failure, it briefly changes state to "retry" but immediately following, the DAG state is set to "FAILED" and so the task (that should be up for retry) gets stuck in the queued state. In this situation, shouldn't the dagrun remain in the "running" state since the failed task is up for retry?

I've spent some time searching documentation and code for how the dagrun changes state, but have been unable to get any clarity.

Comment: I also noticed the same issue and would like to find out a solution to this.

Comment: The issue is currently being tracked [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-695)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has since been fixed in the upcoming Airflow 1.8 release. Refer to the following JIRA tickets:

1. [Retry not honored](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-695)
2. [Retry delay not honored](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-747)